# Is it good to deploy elasticsearch on containers

Tags: elasticsearch, containers

Has anyone tried to run Elasticsearch on containers ? Just wondering would it be a good choice if containers are used for the ES deployment.

Answer (score 1):

We have run ElasticSearch in production for a couple of years now, and it works well.  I don't think the benefits (and drawbacks) are different from any other software running in containers.  Obviously, you need to maintain data in external volumes.  Running on top of containers-as-a-service (such as Kubernetes or Swarm) would certainly present the usual challenges of stateful containers, but these are surmountable.

In fact, there are now [official ElasticSearch](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/) images on Docker Hub.